# What property of $\delta(x)$ is used here?

Tags: summation, dirac-delta

In the solution of an exercise, there is the following equality: $$ \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\theta - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{k}{2}) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\theta - \frac{1}{4} - k) + \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\theta - \frac{3}{4} - k)$$

I struggle to understand what property they used. I searched on the internet but did not find an explanation. May I ask you for help ?

Comment: It is not a property of $\delta$; divide your sum into odd and even terms

Comment: @E-A Uh, didn't think about it. Makes sense now. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: @E-A Im a bit ashamed I did not think about it

Comment: Don't be ashamed! Sometimes we all have a slight mind freeze. Good luck with your work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the comment an answer: Just divide up the sum into its odd and even terms.

Comment: The system says I can only accept your answer in 10 minutes. I will do that ASAP

Comment: Don't worry about it! Thanks anyway.